# Assistance Required to append to existing R Data Frame Object

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to pull back all the historical price information for the ASX200 list of companies. The issue I have is that the R data frame I am using keeps getting overwritten (instead of appended to). So my final dataframe only contains the data from the last ASX200 ticker. Pls see attempt below:

```
library(XML)

url <- "http://www.asx200list.com"
getASX200 <- readHTMLTable(url, which=1, header = TRUE)
codes <- getASX200$Code
codes <- lapply(codes, as.character)

for (i in 1:200) {
  URL2 <- paste("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=", codes[i], ".AX", sep = "")
  dat <- read.csv(URL2)
  dat$Date <- as.Date(dat$Date, "%Y-%m-%d")
  dat$Code <- codes[i]
}
```

Comment: Save everything into a `list` (`L` say)  instead of `dat` - Declare it as `L <- vector("list", length = 200)` outside of your `for` loop then use `L[i]` on the right side and assign `dat` to it in the last line.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Won't this list (L) only provide for 200 rows of data? The response for each iteration will be thousands of rows. Perhaps I have misunderstood?

Comment: `list`s can contain anything, they aren't a square grid like traditional datasets. `L` will contain 200 `data.frames` like `dat` which you can then access like `L[[1]]`

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "L[i] on the right side"?

Comment: `L[i] <- dat` - the left side I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collecting list is a little bit tricky. Here's an example:

```
library(XML)

url <- "http://www.asx200list.com"
getASX200 <- readHTMLTable(url, which=1, header = TRUE)
codes <- getASX200$Code
codes <- lapply(codes, as.character)


datList <- list()

for (i in 1:200) {
  URL2 <- paste("http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=", codes[i], ".AX", sep = "")
  dat <- read.csv(URL2)
  dat$Date <- as.Date(dat$Date, "%Y-%m-%d")
  dat$Code <- codes[i]

  datList <- c(datList, list(dat))
}

print(head(datList[[1]]))
```